# Unable to delete a row in SQLite database in my app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to delete a specific row from table in my SQLite database.
This table contains paths to files.
And I need to delete paths, which contain specific extensions.
And I have troubles with this.
Nothing is deleted from my database.

For example my table name is ALL_PATHS and column name is PATH_NAME
This is the way I am doing this.
I'll be very glad for any help thanks

```
private void deletePath(String extension){
    Database db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + ALL_PATHS + " WHERE lower(" + PATH_NAME + ") LIKE '%" + extension + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Comment: check your query using sqllite tools whether it is correct or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

While it should be

```
db.execSQL(query);
```

Because `DELETE` is a **command**, not a **query** (`SELECT`)

Comment: I'm glad to know that!

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Sir , Great

Answer (score 0):

use Content values

```
String table = "beaconTable";
String whereClause = "_id" + "=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(row) };
db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

Comment: But in my case need to delete rows, which contain special extension in path. So i need to use LIKE keyword. And in your case we are checking, if they are equal.